# Memory usage is the same as data size?

Tags: c++

I'm doing a performance test of the SHA3 algorithm on a variable, I'm checking the execution time of the algorithm for different size of the variable. For this I am using char type and increasing the size of it, but I do not know if I am doing it effectively right. I will use the line of code below to explain my doubt.

```
char[1000] = "A text";
```

I know that each char has a size of 1 Byte. My question is: when I predefine a vector, will the size of the variable be the index of the vector, in this case 1000? Or will the size of the variable be given by the content inside it, in this case by the text, which would be 6 Bytes?

The test that I'm doing is right? Or does not the allocated memory size account for the performance of SHA3? (I ask this because I intend to do the same test with larger values. If I want to, for example, do this test with 20 KBytes, will I have to fill in the variable with 20000 characters?)

I'm using C++.

Comment: `char foo[1000] = "a";` will always reserve 1000 bytes by definition; `char foo[] = "a";` will reserve 2 - remember the null terminator.

Comment: The number in the brackets is the size. Be careful using `sizeof` to determine the size if you pass that variable to a function as it won't work.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Sorry about the dumb question!

Comment: Also: This is an array. Not a vector. A vector is different.

Comment: @MooingDuck Technically, an array is a vector, just not a `std::vector`. It's also a matrix. And a tensor, for that matter.

Answer (score 0):

The amount of memory allocated on the stack by that line of code will be 1,000 bytes. However, what you send to your SHA3 code may only be the number of bytes of the string "A text", depending on how you're calling it, and how it uses the data. If it calculates the length of the string using a function like `strlen()`, then it will likely only iterate over the 6 characters (and 1 NUL byte) of the string and ignore the remaining 993 bytes. So it really depends on how you're using it and how you're calculating the size for your tests.